# Remove first 100 element of variable?

Tags: php

I have this code which stores values in $products. I'm not sure if $products is an array or other thing.

**I need to remove the first 100 values.**

```
// Get all products
$products = Product::getProducts(1, 0, 1000000, 'id_product', 'DESC', false, true, $context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (is_array($products))
  $products = array_slice($product, 100);
```

Refer to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get in deep.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? `$products = array_slice($products, 100, count($products)-1);`

Answer (score 0):

According to [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) menu, the signature is:

> array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )

Since OP wants to remove first 100 elements, it should be:

```
$first_100_elements = array_slice($products, 0, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know if the return type of method Product::getProducts(). You can do it using [gettype()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.gettype.php) or even [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php).

If it is an array, use something like this:

```
$productsWithoutFirst100 = array_slice($product, 100);
```

I will get all the elements of the array, from hundredth element, till the end, excluding the first 100 (from key 0 to 99).

It is a collection of products, so it can be a object that implements Iterable interface. If it is the case, the array_slice function will not work. You can put the object into a foreach, and work on it:

```
$productsArrayWithoutFirst100 = [];
foreach($products as $key =>$product){
    if($key >= 100) $productsArrayWithoutFirst100 = $product;
}
```

Thats a idea, but there is another ways to achieve it. Hope it helps.